# NuGet using HTTP Connect

Tags: amazon-ec2, nuget

I have a server running on EC2 instance in AWS. This server is trying to download packages using nuget. But I'm getting an error saying that the it was impossible to connect to the remote server.

I have already checked the windows firewall and it is disabled and my instance is associated to a security group that allow all traffic from all sources. I checked with fiddler and http connect that nuget executes is being refused. Is there any way to force nuget to download the packages without a connection using simply GET?

Comment: Have you tried HTTPS? It could be that HTTP traffic is blocked on the remote servers, it has nothing to do with Amazon Security groups.

Comment: I have tried anything. The last thing I tried was to create a new instance based on the same image. And magically it worked. Tomorrow I'll try to create an image based on the machine that does not work (we have some work there that cannot be lost) and recreate this machine to see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple restart fixed the problem

Comment: Can you explain your answer a bit more ? How did you restart it ?

Comment: I simply restarted the machine using aws console. And then it started working. I don't exactly why. I think the problem was related to some black magic that aws does.